# Gradle build error with Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, gradlew

```
$ java -version
```

> ```
> java version "1.7.0_80"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
> ```

```
$ gradle -version
```

> ---
>
> ```
> Gradle 2.14
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Build time:   2016-06-14 07:16:37 UTC
> Revision:     cba5fea19f1e0c6a00cc904828a6ec4e11739abc
>
> Groovy:       2.4.4
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
> JVM:          1.7.0_80 (Oracle Corporation 24.80-b11)
> OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.5 x86_64
> ```

I get this error when using Intellij to build a Gradle project

[image]

anyone know what's up with that? Should I use Java 8 instead of Java 7?

Comment: Did you try "default gradle wrapper" ? That might work

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle`? What plugins are you applying in your build?